# How can I use two controllers in the same view with angularJS

Tags: angularjs, html

I bought a template, which has all of its controllers, routes and directives in a single file app.js and this is my first angularJS app,
I have defined Two controllers that I want to use them in the same view,the first is MailNewCtrl1 controller that will handle mail sending option in my form, and the second is FileUploadCtrl1 ,it handles attachments, my problem is that I have this error in the console:

```html
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: FileUploaderProvider <- FileUploader
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.2/$injector/unpr?p0=FileUploaderProvider%20%3C-%20FileUploader
    at REGEX_STRING_REGEXP (http://localhost/ProjetWeb/src/vendor/angular/angular.js:80:12)
    at http://localhost/ProjetWeb/src/vendor/angular/angular.js:3930:19
    at Object.getService [as get] (http://localhost/ProjetWeb/src/vendor/angular/angular.js:4077:39)
    at http://localhost/ProjetWeb/src/vendor/angular/angular.js:3935:45
    at getService (http://localhost/ProjetWeb/src/vendor/angular/angular.js:4077:39)
    at Object.invoke (http://localhost/ProjetWeb/src/vendor/angular/angular.js:4109:13)
    at $get.extend.instance (http://localhost/ProjetWeb/src/vendor/angular/angular.js:8356:21)
    at http://localhost/ProjetWeb/src/vendor/angular/angular.js:7608:13
    at forEach (http://localhost/ProjetWeb/src/vendor/angular/angular.js:347:20)
    at nodeLinkFn (http://localhost/ProjetWeb/src/vendor/angular/angular.js:7607:11) <div ui-view="" class="ng-scope">
```

this is how I used the two controllers:

```html
<div ng-controller="MailNewCtrl1">
.........contact form(email,subject,message).........
<div class="form-group" ng-controller="FileUploadCtrl1"  nv-file-drop="" uploader="uploader" filters="queueLimit, customFilter" >......<!--table of attachements!-->
.............</div>
</div>
```

app.js in which I defined the controllers:

```js
'use strict';
angular.module('app', [
    'ngAnimate',
    'ngCookies',
    'ngResource',
])
.controller('FileUploadCtrl1', ['$scope', 'FileUploader', function($scope, FileUploader) {
    var uploader = $scope.uploader = new FileUploader({
        url: 'upload.php'
    });

    // FILTERS

    uploader.filters.push({
        name: 'customFilter',
        fn: function(item /*{File|FileLikeObject}*/, options) {
            return this.queue.length < 10;
        }
    });
.....//the code is too long,this the controller in which I have problem
```

thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to inject a `FileUploader` service, but don't appear to have defined that service in your `app` module, nor are you depending on another module that might provide it for you.

You will need to do one or the other.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing the `FileUploader` is provided in another module. Make sure your module is *dependend* on that module:

```
angular.module('app', [
    'ngAnimate',
    'ngCookies',
    'ngResource',
    'FileUploader' // Name of the module goes here
])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var items = angular.module('items', []);
var text = angular.module('text', []);

text.controller('TextController', function ($scope) {
    //Controller Code Here
});

items.controller('ItemController', function ($scope) {
    //Controller Code Here
});
```